# Kubernetes Postgres Pod not reachable

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a K8s Cluster with couple of pods. I have a postgres pod of type Deployment which simply runs a "postgres:12" image

```
docker pull postgres:12
```

the pod is named "metadatadb"

for which I'm exposing a service with the same name "metadatadb".

there are other pods of type Cronjob that are dependent on it. These Cronjobs run containers that connect to "metadatadb" to do some CRUD operations. from time to time I see some of these cronjob instances failing with the below error

> ERROR [08001] could not translate host name "metadatadb" to address: Name or service not known

This error happens rarely (which means in most of the times the cronjob runs and connects successfully). I can't figure out why.

Thank you

Comment: As Thomas mentioned in the answer, it looks like DNS issue in the cluster. There's a [debugging DNS resolution article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) - follow it and hope it will be more clear. + check logs in `coreDNS` if there are any issues/errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the result of a missing `Service` or a problem with the Cluster DNS.

Background: A pod does not get a DNS entry, if you want to connect to a pod you need the internal IP of it. To create DNS names (and internal load balancing with a service ip) you need to create a service.

Comment: I do have a service named also "metadatadb" and as I mentioned, most of the times the cronjob instance connects to the service and does the job, it's only in some cases where it throws this error

Comment: Looks like a problem with your DNS service inside your cluster.